# Resource leak across dll boundaries

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, memory-leaks

I have a third party (open-source) dll written in C, let's call it `library_c_style_0.2.dll`. In my C++ application I have to call methods from this dll. I will make calls to these methods from inside a dll, say `library0.1.dll`, loaded by my `application.exe`. After using the dll `library_c_style_0.2.dll`(which I load at run-time using LoadLibrary) I'm calling FreeLibrary. I can see App Verifier complaining that `A heap allocation was leaked.` I ignore this and continue and I see failures in some unrelated parts of my app starting to fail at, `HeapAlloc`.

Thus to verify this I used crtdbg, and wrote a mini simulation of the scenario like the following. The export from `library_c_style_0.2.dll` is like so,

```
int hello_from_c_style_library(const char* string_to_print)
{
    _CrtMemState s1, s2, s3;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1); //create on checkpoint

    int length = strlen(string_to_print);
    char * c = malloc(length+1); //allocate memory for the sting
    StringCchCopyA(c, length + 1, string_to_print);
    printf("%s", c);

    //comment the folling lines if you pretend that you will foget to free
    //free(c);

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s3); //one more after resource allocation
    if (_CrtMemDifference(&s2, &s3, &s1))//find the difference now
    {
        //returns 1 if memory is leaked; 0 otherwise
        OutputDebugString(L"Memory Leaked!!!");
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my `library0.1.dll` that will load this at run-time would be like so,

```
HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("library_c_style_0.2.dll"));
if (hinstLib != NULL)
{
    //GetProcAddress of hello_from_c_style_library
    //call the funtion
    //we are now done with the third party dll, free it

    FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
}
```

But, if I uncomment the `free(c)` all is well. (and there was no problem when I wrote the sample `library_c_style_0.2.dll` in C++ with operator `new`, though it leaked)

As we can see `library_c_style_0.2.dll` leaks the memory that it allocated for `c` and I see the call to `FreeLibrary(hinstLib)` failing with the error `A heap allocation was leaked.` on AppVerifier.

The output window dump from CRT is as follows,

```
Memory Leaked!!!Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
library_c_style_0.2.c(23) : {69} normal block at 0x08B31FF0, 6 bytes long.
 Data: <hello > 68 65 6C 6C 6F 00 
Object dump complete.
```

as we can see `hello`'s 6 bytes are leaked.

This is just a simulation, the actual third party dll (for which library_c_style_0.2.dll is the placeholder here) is leaking some resource and is causing my app to crash.

What can I do ? Is there a way I can deal with this without having to look into the third party C dll that leaks the resource ? If I ignore this, it crashes some unrelated part of my C++ app on `HeapAlloc`.

Why does this happen ? Any pointers will be helpful. I'm new to the Windows environment. Does every dll have its own heap ?! Is the error thrown because, I try to free the library while it is holding a resource ?

Is there a workaround to avoid looking into `library_c_style_0.2.dll`'s code ? Is there a problem with the way I link to the run-time ? I'm statically linking to it now. In production I use `Multi-threaded (/MT)`and I can see the leaky dll (which is a pretty huge code base) also uses the same.

I would want to understand the basics. Why does resource leak cause a failure here ? Please explain the internals about, what exactly is going on here.

Comment: It will be hard to tell without looking into the code. Try simple things. Does leak if you don't call any method, just load the library? If so, yikes. If not, then find a method that causes tis. On WIdnows you might find it tnds to allocate things at the same place  and can set a break point programmatically when that memory address is allocated - you could then debug where the problem is. More simply, you may find the "contract" for the API is they allocate stuff but you are supoosed to free it. Are therre any docs/comments/developers to ask?

Comment: @doctorlove thanks for your comment. Just loading and unloading does not crash my app. As you mentioned, I can find the specific function call after calling which this issue happens. But, why ? Why does a resource leak cause a crash here ? that too, at some completely innocent part of my app ? `int main { int* newInteger = new int; return 0;}` does not crash, in the same lines why does the leak here, cause failure ? Can you please explain what exactly is causing the crash here ? I will read through the API contracts, but, help me understand the issue. CRT linkage is same everywhere.

Comment: I'd need more details on the crash. Try to make a core dump and see what that tells you?